# Google App Script - Why can I not use methods for an input?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I am trying to create a custom function for Google Spreadsheets, but I'm encountering a problem.
This piece of Google App Script code returns the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")

```
function FOO(input) {
      var x = input.length
      return x
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

The following works and throws no errors:

```
function FOO(input) { 
  return input
```

Also, none of the methods for input works, such as `input.map`, `input.values`, etc.

Comment: Although from your question, I'm not sure whether how you run your script, I think that if you directly run ``FOO()`` at the script editor, such error occurs at the 1st script, and 2nd script occurs no error. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a spreadsheet, `=FOO(A1)` returns 1 and `=FOO(A1:A5)` returns 5. So that's working correctly.

[image]

In the script editor, if you simply run `FOO()`, then you will receive an error because you didn't pass in the `input`. You need to create a test function and run it instead.

```
function test_FOO() {
  var input = [1];
  Logger.log(FOO(input));
}
```

[image]